# How to specify figure names when `knit`ting with `fig.keep='all'`

Tags: r, knitr

I'm using `knitr` to generate reports. However, I often first prepare "internal" documents which contain all plots, and then for a final report or paper want to include only some of the figures.

Say, I have a set of systematically produced figures, say I loop over my specimen:

```
<<sample, fig.keep = 'all'>>=
specimen <- c("436a", "783a", "10b")
for (s in specimen) # in reality it would e.g. be levels (specimen)
   plot (results [s])
@
```

This will produce a number of files `figures/sample1.pdf`, `figures/sample2.pdf`, etc.
While the numbering with 1, 2, ... is good for the knitr-generated report, if I want to include one of the plots in a paper it is cumbersome and error prone to find out which .pdf belongs to which sample.

How can I tell `knitr` to use file names like `"figures/sample-436a.pdf"`?

I tried `<<fig.path = sprintf ("figures/sample-%s", s)>>=`, but that doesn't work: `s` is unknown, so I guess `fig.path` is evaluated right at the beginning of the chunk processing, not when saving the chunk.

PS: One obvious way to reduce the risk of errors are titles, but that is IMHO ugly in a paper.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but can you print the titles in same colour as your background, e.g. white, to make them invisible, while still having them available for debugging?

Comment: @PatrickT: it is not for debugging, but e.g. for picking the right of such a series for a presentation or the longer paper. And an invisible title doesn't help with that - visible titles help if readable in the file manager's icon preveiw.

Answer (score 5):

Good question. Not sure if this could be a satisfactory answer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<prepare-src, include=FALSE>>=
s = names(iris)[-5]
# construct the source document
src = sprintf('<<sample-%s>>=
hist(iris[,"%s"], col="gray", border="white")
@', s, s)
@

% evaluate the source
\Sexpr{knit(text = src)}

\end{document}
```

In your case, you only need to decide which specimen to go into `s`.

Comment: Thanks, Yihui. I admit I was hoping for something more elegant, but I'll use this at least for my personal stuff. My collaborators would probably go mad if I sent them such files, and it would not convince them to switch over to `knitr`/`Sweave`...

Comment: The key difficulty is for animations. I have to use fig1, fig2, ... otherwise it should be possible to name the figure files in your own way. Let me think more about this.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way (albeit a little complicated) to achieve the same using hooks. We use two hooks, a chunk hook that renames the figures based on a chunk option `fig.names`, and an output hook that replaces the names in the document. I am sure this code can be refactored, or even inserted into `knitr` to make it work asis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<main, echo = F>>=
knit_hooks$set(fig.names = function(before, options, envir){
  if (!before) {
    from = dir('figure', pattern = opts_current$get('label'), full = TRUE)
    to = sprintf('%s.pdf', file.path('figure', 
      paste(opts_current$get('label'), options$fig.names, sep = "-")))
    file.rename(from, to)
  }
})
knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options){
  if (is.null(options$fig.names)){
     knitr:::.chunk.hook.tex(x, options)
  } else {
    chunk_name = opts_current$get('label')
    x = gsub(sprintf('%s[0-9]', chunk_name), 
      sprintf("%s-%s", chunk_name, options$fig.names), x)
    knitr:::.chunk.hook.tex(x, options)
  }
});
@


<<iris, fig.names = letters[1:4]>>=
invisible(lapply(iris[,-5], hist, col = 'gray', border = 'white'))
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Ramnath, I'll build my hooks from this basis. A few details are needed to make it fully working. 1) `to` should capture only the numbered files (the current version fails once the renamed filed exist!). a) `to` needs to be sorted appropriately (10 > 9), and 3) the `\includegraphics` output needs some more care, too: at the moment, `iris-a` is included 4 times.